# Getting the following error in my Service class and my Controller: Cannot cast java.lang.String to org.bson.Document

Tags: java, spring-boot, postman

Here is the controller class:

```
package com.example.justin_revature_project.controllers;

import com.example.justin_revature_project.exceptions.InvalidInputException;
import com.example.justin_revature_project.exceptions.SpecFileNotFoundException;
import com.example.justin_revature_project.exceptions.UserNotFoundException;
import com.example.justin_revature_project.models.MetadataFile;
import com.example.justin_revature_project.models.ParsedFile;
import com.example.justin_revature_project.models.SpecFile;
import com.example.justin_revature_project.models.User;
import com.example.justin_revature_project.services.MetadataFileService;
import com.example.justin_revature_project.services.ParsedFileService;
import com.example.justin_revature_project.services.SpecFileService;
import com.example.justin_revature_project.services.UserService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.List;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/users/{username}/file")
public class ParsedFileController {
    private ParsedFileService parsedFileService;
    private SpecFileService specFileService;
    private UserService userService;
    private MetadataFileService metadataFileService;

    @Autowired
    public ParsedFileController(ParsedFileService parsedFileService, SpecFileService specFileService, UserService userService, MetadataFileService metadataFileService){
        this.parsedFileService = parsedFileService;
        this.specFileService = specFileService;
        this.userService = userService;
        this.metadataFileService = metadataFileService;
    }

    @GetMapping("")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    public List<ParsedFile> getParsedFilesByUserId(@PathVariable String username) throws UserNotFoundException {
        return this.parsedFileService.findParsedFilesByUserId(this.userService.findByUsername(username).getId());
    }

    @PostMapping("specFile/{specFileName}")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.ACCEPTED)
    public ParsedFile postNewParsedFileWithSpecFileName(@RequestParam MultipartFile flatFile, @PathVariable String specFileName, @PathVariable String username)
            throws SpecFileNotFoundException, IOException, UserNotFoundException, InvalidInputException {
        User currUser = this.userService.findByUsername(username);
        SpecFile specFile = this.specFileService.findByName(specFileName);
        ParsedFile newParsedFile = this.parsedFileService.insertFile(flatFile, specFile, currUser);

        // Add Parsed FileID to User who uploaded the file.
        this.userService.addParsedFileId(newParsedFile.getId(), currUser);
        // TODO: Find a way to update MetadataID field in parsedFile
        this.metadataFileService.insertMetadataFileLocal(new MetadataFile(newParsedFile.getId(), LocalDate.now()),
                "src\\main\\java\\resources\\" + currUser.getUsername() + "\\" + newParsedFile.getId().toHexString());

        return newParsedFile;
    }
}
```

Here is the Service class:

```
package com.example.justin_revature_project.services;

import com.example.justin_revature_project.exceptions.InvalidInputException;
import com.example.justin_revature_project.models.ParsedFile;
import com.example.justin_revature_project.models.SpecFile;
import com.example.justin_revature_project.models.User;
import com.example.justin_revature_project.repositores.ParsedFileRepository;
import org.bson.Document;
import org.bson.types.ObjectId;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;


import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

@Service
public class ParsedFileService {
    private ParsedFileRepository parsedFileRepository;

    @Autowired
    public ParsedFileService(ParsedFileRepository parsedFileRepository){
        this.parsedFileRepository = parsedFileRepository;
    }

    //TODO: ADD METADATA ID AND STORE FLAT FILE TO BLOCK STORAGE
    public ParsedFile insertFile(MultipartFile flatFile, SpecFile specFile, User user) throws IOException, InvalidInputException {
        //TODO: Create New EXCEPTION if wanted
        //User Cannot use specfile that it did not create
        if(!user.getListOfSpecFileIds().contains(specFile.getId())){
            throw new InvalidInputException(String.format("Cannot find specFile: %s in the user: %s", specFile.getName(), user.getUsername()));
        }
        ParsedFile newParsedFile = new ParsedFile();
        Document docParsedFileInfo = new Document();

        String fileContent = HelperForService.parseFileToString(flatFile);
        Document specFileDoc = specFile.getDocOfFields();
        for(String fieldName : specFileDoc.keySet()){
            //TODO: Add Class Types
            Document fieldDoc = specFileDoc.get(fieldName, Document.class);
            String fieldValue = fileContent.substring(
                            fieldDoc.getInteger("start_pos"), fieldDoc.getInteger("end_pos") + 1)
                    .trim();
            docParsedFileInfo.put(fieldName, fieldValue);
        }

        newParsedFile.setUserId(user.getId());
        newParsedFile.setSpecId(specFile.getId());
        newParsedFile.setFileInfo(docParsedFileInfo);
        ParsedFile parsedFileWithId = this.parsedFileRepository.save(newParsedFile);

        //TODO: Replace with Non-Local save
        HelperForService.uploadFileLocally(fileContent, "src\\main\\resources\\flatFileStorage\\" + user.getUsername(), parsedFileWithId.getId().toHexString());

        return parsedFileWithId;
    }

    public List<ParsedFile> findParsedFilesByUserId(ObjectId userID){
        return this.parsedFileRepository.findByUserId(userID);
    }
```

Here is the output from postman:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/EexyV.png

Here is the spec file:

```
{
  "name": "example_spec",
  "docOfFields": {
    "field_1": "date",
    "field_2": "date",
    "field_3": "date",
    "field_4": "date"
  }
}
```

I am trying to pinpoint the issue. I am not sure where the conversion from String to Document is located. Does it have something to do with the .get call?

This line it states in the logs is the source of the error:

```
Document fieldDoc = specFileDoc.get(fieldName, Document.class);
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The Javadoc for the `get` method says: "Throws: ClassCastException - if the value of the given key is not of type T"